# Discord.py Discord screen transfer feature

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any way that a DiscordBot in python can do a screen transfer in discord?
Have so far unfortunately no solution found on the internet...

Comment: There isn't really a way to do this within the client, you could have the bot share a link to a web app that you could write for screenshare functionality, however. Bots cannot access other users' screens.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has not included any forms of "screenshare" in their documentation, which most likely means it is not possible. It could also not be a feature as it could breach Discord's guidelines, as people could use bots for wrong purposes, including streaming content which would then put Discord into a lot of intellectual property issues.

The only forms of sharing in voice channels were bots sharing music or pre-recorded files by what it includes in the documentation. Hope this helps, included the documentation if you need more information.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/voice